# Constant Force Pendulum (undamped)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, applications

How does one sketch the derivation of the equation of motion for a planar pendulum of length l and mass m in constant gravity g, subject to a constant torque force F (directed along the tangent to the circular trajectory of m). I know that the normal derivation for an undamped and unforced pendulum would be:
$$\theta''+ksin\theta=0$$ I am unsure however on how to add the constant force aspect?

Comment: what do you mean by: "a constant torque force" ?

Comment: Basically a constant force directed along the tangent of the pendulums circular trajectory. As in, imagine someone was pushing the pendulum around and around at a constant force, F.

Comment: It was a question posed to me by a friend? I imagine he is correct in assuming it is a pendulum, this was his wording, so I may be interpreting it incorrectly. I thought the same thing KonKan

Comment: look, a constant force cannot be tangent to the trajectory. By definition, a tangent to a circular trajectory is variable (as a vector)

Comment: Okay, I will tell him the wording is wrong. Apologies

Answer (score -1):

The net force on an object is equal to mass times acceleration, hence
$$\vec F+k\vec x=m\vec x''$$
where $x$ is the (linear) distance from the equilibrium position. The vectoral sum of the applied force $\vec F$ and the restoring force $kx$ may not be in a particularly understandable direction, but the equation holds.